# Showing that a derivative is positive

Tags: calculus

I would like to show that the function

$\frac{1}{x}\log(\frac{4}{x+2}-\exp(-0.5x))$

is increasing in $x$ for $x>0$. I can plot it and see it, and also calculate the derivative, but I don't manage to show that the derivative is positive. Does anyone have a good hint?

Comment: If you show your working ... ie the derivative ... then it should be possible to show you why it must be positive

Comment: The derivative is $(\frac{x}{\frac{4}{x+2}-\exp(-0.5x)}(-\frac{4}{(x+2)^2}+0.5\exp(-0.5x))-\log(\frac{4}{x+2}-\exp(-0.5x)))(\frac{1}{x^2})$

Comment: I think your derivative should be  $\frac{1}{x}. \left( \frac{-\frac{4}{(x+2)^2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{\frac{4}{x+2}-e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}\right)-\frac{1}{x^2}.\ln \left( \frac{4}{x+2} - e^{\frac{-x}{2}} \right)$

Comment: now bear in mind that you are looking for where $x>0$ and see where you go

Comment: I agree with your derivative but the second term is positive and subtracted so it is not immediate to me that the derivative is positive. How can I show that the first term is bigger than the second?

Comment: The second term has a factor $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and logs grow slowly so that may help